# i want to create a urlpattern according to users username

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i want to load my profile html with user username on urlpattern
my views.py

```
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from accounts import views as user_views
from . import views

# Template Urls!
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('Skolar/',views.base, name= 'base'),
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', views.my_login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('<username>',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('EditProfile/',views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized urls like this

Update views.py like this

```
def profile(request, username="default"):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

update urls.py like this

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from accounts import views as user_views
from . import views

# Template Urls!
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('Skolar/',views.base, name= 'base'),
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', views.my_login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('<str:username>',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('EditProfile/',views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
]
```

checkout [urls in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) for details

Comment: i would like to make it better. please consider that any url rather than defined will be redirectd to profile. and username field can be alphanum so as per my view url should be like path('username/<slug:username>/',views.profile, name='profile')

Comment: not working same error it says Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found

Comment: @harshilsuthar i agree with you on adding a specific pattern in url before username to prevent unintended redirects and using something like `path('user/<slug:username>/',views.profile, name='profile')`, but the solution given by me do support alphanum usernames.

Comment: @shreyashmishra if you are using reverse anywhere in code, you need to update it like `reverse('profile', kwargs={'username':'whatever username'})` and username could be dynamic.

Comment: @HemantMalik my mistake, your code does support alphanumeric.

Comment: then what you suggest

Comment: i am not using reverse anywhere in my code @HemantMalik

Comment: @shreyashmishra are you using something like `{% url 'profile' %}` in any of your templates?

Comment: try updating `{% url 'accounts:profile' %}` with `{% url 'accounts:profile' username='someusername' %}`